# Управление пакетами в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Использую `requirements.txt`
Решил, следуя методикам, делать `pip freeze`. Но, столкнулся с такой проблемой, что, например, `opencv-python` той версии, что установил `pip` просто нет на linux.

### Вопрос 1:

- Следует ли использовать `pip freeze`, или стоит оставлять в `requirements.txt` только те пакеты, что использую в проекте. То есть игнорировать зависимости пакетов из `requirements.txt`.

### Вопрос 2:

- Как указывать версии для таких случаев, как с `opencv-python`? На данный момент я просто убрал версию.

Как поступаете Вы в таких ситуациях?

Comment: «только те пакеты, что использую в проекте» — конечно. // «просто нет на linux» — значит установите ту, которая есть, наверное?

Comment: «только те пакеты, что использую в проекте», - ок. Допустим, мы используем Flask. Он использует "зависимость 1". Если следовать этой схеме, то исходная среда не воссоздаться. Тут pip freeze, или тупо flask записать?

Comment: // Если на винде pip install установил версию, который нет на linux, - как быть? Или не указывать версию? Скажем: FlaskWindowsVersion = 1.1, FlaskLinuxVersion = 1.0

Comment: При установке Flask автоматически установятся все его зависимости, которые прописаны в его собственном requirements.txt (точнее [install_requires](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/9039534eee6a87da98a1dee9e4338d1b73e861f8/setup.py#L6-L11) но не суть), и исходная среда будет замечательно воссоздана

Comment: Зависимости для Flask той версии, что мы указали... Звучит логично. Но зачем тогда lock file, в pipenv, или, npm, например?

Comment: Не знаю, я их не использую. В теории говорят, что для максимального точного воссоздания окружения, но на практике лично я не вижу в этом смысла и являюсь противником такого подхода (однако моё мнение может быть неверным)

Comment: В любом случае, если вы хотите сделать переносимость между windows и linux, то точно воссоздать окружение всё равно не получится по той банальной причине, что windows это не linux, а linux это не windows :) А ведь ещё существует к примеру macos (и в том же npm вы могли часто видеть сообщение, что зависимость fsevents не установлена, потому что текущая система не macos, и никакого точного воссоздания окружения в итоге не получается)

Comment: Ок, а касательно второго вопроса - "скажем: FlaskWindowsVersion = 1.1, FlaskLinuxVersion = 1.0". Как тут, просто указать Flask, без версий?

Comment: Так и указывайте, без версий